# Radio button with an <a> element inside as label

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong here? 
The links still work and the radio buttons can still be clicked, only the label doesn't work. 
How do I have to rewrite it to make it work?

Html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <input type="radio" name="RADIO" id="Oneradio">
            <a href="#ONE" aria-controls="ONE" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="margin-right: 20px">
                <label for="Oneradio">
                    ONE
                </label>
            </a>
        </input>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <input type="radio" name="RADIO" id="Tworadio">
            <a href="#TWO" aria-controls="TWO" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                <label for="Tworadio">
                    TWO
                </label>
            </a>
        </input>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="ONE">
        ONE Content
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="TWO">
        TWO Content
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is that if you click it, you will see the content and the radio button is checked.

https://jsfiddle.net/ye361u24/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the radiobuttons and added a class and a value. Then you can use some javascript to perform the change of the tab-pane

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active">
    <input type="radio" name="RADIO" id="Oneradio" class="radiogroup" value="ONE">
        <a href="#ONE" aria-controls="ONE" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="margin-right: 20px" id="onelink">
            <label for="Oneradio" onclick="$('#Oneradio').prop('checked', true);">
                ONE
            </label>
        </a>
    </input>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
    <input type="radio" name="RADIO" id="Tworadio" class="radiogroup" value="TWO">
        <a href="#TWO" aria-controls="TWO" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="twolink">
            <label for="Tworadio" onclick="$('#Tworadio').prop('checked', true);">
                TWO
            </label>
        </a>
    </input>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="ONE">
        ONE Content
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="TWO">
        TWO Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.radiogroup').change(function(e){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if (selectedValue == "ONE"){
        $('#onelink').click();
    }else{
        $('#twolink').click();
    }
});
```

The example: https://jsfiddle.net/3q9vaxue/3/

Comment: If I click the links, the radio button shows it is clicked, but it isnt checked.

Comment: I included the onclick from Vlad to also include the radio button checked if the links are clicked

Answer (score 2):

Your label needs to sit outside your input code. Otherwise it cannot find the associated id. Nesting it like this may seem logical as it is all 'linked together', however they must be treated as separate entities.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active">
    <input type="radio" name="RADIO" id="Oneradio">    
    </input>
    <a href="#ONE" aria-controls="ONE" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="margin-right: 20px">
            <label for="Oneradio">
                ONE
            </label>
    </a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
    <input type="radio" name="RADIO" id="Tworadio">
    </input>
    <a href="#TWO" aria-controls="TWO" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <label for="Tworadio">
                TWO
            </label>
    </a>
</li>
```

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="ONE">
    ONE Content
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="TWO">
    TWO Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The link will prevent label's action

Here's a fast inline trick you can do to workaround:

```
<label for="Oneradio" onclick="$('#Oneradio').prop('checked', true);">
  ONE
</label>
```

This is beside your label needs to sit outside your input code.

https://jsfiddle.net/ye361u24/28/

Comment: The problem is it does not change the label if you just click the radio buttons

Comment: You're right. Your updated solution seems to be complete